# Constrained underdetermined least-squares over two variables

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming

If I have the problem $$\min_{x,y} \|Ax - b\|_2^2 \quad s.t. \quad Cx = D^T y$$ (for $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $m < n$, $C \in \mathbb{S}^{n}$, $D \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ full row rank $k < n$ orthogonal projection, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^k$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$), how can I formulate the problem as a system of linear equations to solve? I want to enforce a the relationship between $x$ and $y$ as a projection constraint but retain both $x$ and $y$ in the formulation (i.e., not eliminate $y$ by requiring the orthogonal projection $(I- D^T D) Cx = 0$).

My Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda) = x^T A^T Ax - 2x^T A^Tb + \lambda^T(Cx - D^T y)$ gives:

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_x \mathcal{L} = 0 &\implies A^T Ax + C^T \lambda = A^T b \\
\nabla_y \mathcal{L} = 0 &\implies D\lambda = 0 \\
\nabla_x \mathcal{L} = 0 &\implies Cx = D^Ty \\
\end{align}
$$

---

I tried to put this into a single, symmetric system so that I could use MINRES:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A^T A & C^T  & 0 \\
C     & -D^T & 0 \\
0     & 0    & D
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
A^T b \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but my $D^T$ dimension doesn't fit within the dimensions of $C$ and $C^T$. What am I missing / doing wrong?

Comment: Compute the least-squares solution for the unconstrained problem and then exploit the fact that $\rm D$ has full row rank. You are complicating things.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm unsure of how to do this. I have $n > m$, so the system is underdetermined, and $x$ is a nuisance parameter. I'm trying to solve this two ways with MOSEK in CVX python (full formulation vs minimum-norm for $x$ then $D D^T Cx = y$ for $y$) but seem to be getting different results for $y$ in these cases. So I'm confused about how I might ensure I recover the same $y$ in the second case as the first.

Comment: To add on, I want some type of projection relationship to hold between $x$ and $y$, and I want this relationship to pick out the appropriate $x$ from the set of $x$ that satisfy $Ax=b$ to control how I get $y$. I could rephrase the problem in terms of a projection constraint on $x$ and only optimize over $x$ (i.e., like $(I - D^T D)Cx = 0$), but I want to keep $y$ in my formulation. Btw, I edited the Q to reflect the underdetermined part, thanks for your comment

Comment: $C$ and $C^T$ are in the wrong entries of the block matrix. So are $D$ and $D^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following **constrained least-squares** problem in $\mathrm x_1 \in \mathbb R^{n_1}$ and $\mathrm x_2 \in \mathbb R^{n_2}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm A_1 \mathrm x_1 - \mathrm b \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm C_1 \mathrm x_1 + \mathrm C_2 \mathrm x_2 = \mathrm 0\end{array}$$

We rewrite the original problem as follows

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm C \mathrm x = \mathrm 0\end{array}$$

where $\mathrm x := \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x_1\\ \mathrm x_2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathrm A := \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A_1 & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathrm C := \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm C_1 & \mathrm C_2\end{bmatrix}$. Let the Lagrangian be

$$\mathcal L (\mathrm x, \mu) := \frac 12 \| \mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b \|_2^2 + \mu^{\top} \mathrm C \mathrm x$$

Taking the partial derivatives and finding where they vanish, we obtain the following linear system

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A & \mathrm C^\top\\ \mathrm C & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ \mu\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A^\top \mathrm b\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

which can be rewritten as follows

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A_1^\top \mathrm A_1 & \mathrm O & \mathrm C_1^\top\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O & \mathrm C_2^\top\\ \mathrm C_1 & \mathrm C_2 & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x_1\\ \mathrm x_2\\ \mu\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A_1^\top \mathrm b\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$